# How to css per rows change color for on "responsive" div's

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="divs" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
</div>
```

[image: responsive grid]

Comment: Do you want to set a color for even rows and another color for odd rows?

Comment: That's not possible with pure css.

Comment: @MohammedAhmed  yes, first row divs change AND second row divs change AND ...

Comment: CSS can only select **elements** and wrapping rows is not creating elements. This is not possible with CSS.